# How i restart service of JMX server in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, jmx

I killed the process that used the port 7199, then i wanted to run cassandra using

```
 cassandra -f -R
```

But I had this message :

```
INFO  05:45:43 Initializing system.schema_functions
INFO  05:45:43 Initializing system.schema_aggregates
INFO  05:45:43 Not submitting build tasks for views in keyspace system as storage service is not initialized
INFO  05:45:43 Configured JMX server at: ****service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:7199/jmxrmi****
Exception (java.lang.RuntimeException) encountered during startup: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: FSWriteError in
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: FSWriteError in at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFuture(FBUtilities.java:403)
```

I want to run the process that use the port 7199,

I killed that because I had a message the port 7199 already used.

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill the process completely. If it is standalone use this,

```
$ ps auwx | grep cassandra
$ sudo kill pid
```

or `$ sudo service cassandra stop` if you have a local setup

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps-

```
$ jps
```

You see some processes running. For example:

```
9107 Jps
1112 CassandraDaemon
```

Then kill the CassandraDaemon process by the process id you see after executing jps. In my example, here process id 1112 for CassandraDaemon.

```
$ kill -9 1112
```

Then check processes again after a while-

```
$ jps
```

You will see CassandraDaemon will no longer be available.

```
9170 Jps
```

Then remove your saved_caches and start cassandra again.